# app engine query filter by 'id' range of entities, ignoring ancestor(s)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have entities like these ones:

Entity [products(147)]
Entity [manufacturer(23)/products(131)]
Entity [manufacturer(17)/products(131)]

Now, I'm trying to find using a Query all the entities of kind 'products' which have an ID from 100 and up. Ones like the above 147 & 131.

The problem is that I don't know how to ask for these, "detaching" the ancestor from it in the query.

Tried these:

*Not working*:

```
SELECT __key__ FROM products WHERE ID >= 100
```

***Partially working***:

```
SELECT __key__ FROM products WHERE __key__ >= 100
```

This is how I insert the query filter:

```
query.addFilter("__key__", FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, KeyFactory.createKey("products", 100));
```

This partially working one gives the proper results ONLY for 'root' entities, i.e ones without an ancestor.

Any way to modify it so it ignore ancestor(s)? Thanks!

Comment: Note: I know I might get entities with the same id (but different ancestor). That's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in way to do this, because this query is meaningless. IDs are allocated such that they are unique for a given kind **and parent**. You can't rely on IDs alone to uniquely identify an entity if it might have different parent entities, so it's pretty meaningless to query for a range of IDs regardless of parent.

Comment: The term "meaningless" depends. For me this requirement is meaningful. Anyway, actually as I see at the docs under "Kindless Queries", it is possible to ask for "anything". This implies that entities of same kind with same ID are retrievable. Well, I guess I'll have to handle it somehow, or find a way around, hopefully.

Comment: By the way Nick, when I do two queries, one with an ASC sort and the other with a DEC sort on __key__, and without the filter, it gives me all the entities ignoring ancestor(s). Maybe a side-effect? That's by the way gave me the hope that I can also filter these queries this way.

Comment: @Poni That's the intended behaviour - keys are effectively paths, so they'll be sorted by those paths. Why do you want to filter like this, given that IDs aren't unique between entities with different parents? If you really need to do this, you'll have to add a property to your model that contains just the ID, and index that.

Comment: Ping... So did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem.